# Is There a way to permanently apply replaygain info to many flac files?

Tags: audio, conversion, foobar2000, flac, replaygain

I ripped a bunch of CDs to flac, with replaygain, a while ago. What I am trying to do now is permanently apply the replaygain to the files so it is not just a meta tag.

This way, I can batch convert all of these new files to AAC using NeroAAC in the foobar2000 environment.

Here is a list in case that was confusing:

1. Batch apply replaygain within flacs, save as new flacs
2. Batch convert new flacs to AAC

The volume will be consistent this way, and AAC can be played on nearly everything, so I have some portability.

Comment: The whole point of replaygain (and I suppose flac) is not to have to do any changes to the original file.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I know that. I won't be changing the original flac files. I want to apply the replaygain so that the volume is normalized on devices which don't support it (pretty much every device). In addition, I will be encoding them to a lossy format later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some tinkering, the answer is yes, and step 1 can be eliminated entirely. Under "Converter Setup", ReplayGain can be applied using the DSP options.